# AS3 : How to compare 2 array containing objects using 1 for loop only?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have 2 array having objects of different length

```
 var arr : Array = [{name : "aa", id : "0"}, {name : "bb", id : "1"}, {name : "cc", id : "2"}];

 var arrTemp : Array = [{name : "ee", id : "0"}, {name : "hh", id : "1"}, {name : "cc", id : "2"}, {name : "gg", id : "3"}];
```

Now i don't want to use 2 for loops to traverse arrays. Is it possible to search via using any property like indexOf or filter for the same.

Currently i am using code below which is not right i guess

```
for(var i:* in arr)
{       
    if( arr[i].indexOf( arrTemp[i].name ) > -1 )
    {
        trace(i)
    }
}
```

Help will be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing you have posted contains multidimensional arrays. You showed us 2 arrays, each of them are filled with simple Objects. What does this have to do with multidimensional arrays?

Comment: @DodgerThud thanks, updated the question, now can you help me to solve this.

Comment: I would if I could but I don't think I understand your question. You don't want to use 2 loops, but in the code you show you are already only using one foor loop.

Comment: @DodgerThud As i mentioned i don't want to use 2 for loops.

Comment: But you're not using 2 for loops, you're using 1.

Comment: yes i am using 1 loop cause i want to use only one loop for  this. @DodgerThud

Comment: you don't have multidimensional arrays so the only way to traverse your 2 arrays is to use a loop for each one. It's a wrong question for a wrong problem so there's no answer to give.

Comment: i don't think so its a wrong question dude. btw thanks @BotMaster

Comment: it's a question about multidimensional arrays which you don't have in the first place how is it not a wrong question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to check `arr[i].name` `indexOf` instead of `arr[i]`. Code should work like this:

```
var arr : Array = [{name : "aa", id : "0"}, {name : "bb", id : "1"}, {name : "cc", id : "2"},{name : "ee", id : "0"}];
var arrTemp : Array = [{name : "aa", id : "0"}];

function decideWhichArray():void {
    if(arr.length <= arrTemp.length){
        var dif = arrTemp.length - arr.length;
        for(var i=0;i< dif;i++){
            var newObj:Object = new Object();
            newObj.name = null;
            newObj.id = null;
            arr.push(newObj)
        }
    }
    else{
        var difAgain = arr.length - arrTemp.length;
        for(var j=0;j< difAgain;j++){
            var newObjSecond:Object = new Object();
            newObjSecond.name = null;
            newObjSecond.id = null;
            arrTemp.push(newObjSecond)
        }
    }
    checkResult(arr,arrTemp);
}

function checkResult(arr1,arr2):void {
    for(var i:* in arr1)
    {       
        if( arr1[i].name.indexOf( arr2[i].name ) > -1 )
        {
            trace(arr1[i].name);
        }
    }
}

decideWhichArray()
```

Comment: thanks @Özgür Ersil it works but  what if both array's are different in length.